# Validation numericTextBox in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

How can I do validation for numericTextBox using Kendo UI? Because I have put required but there is nothing happen here. It shoul be validation when there is no input value when clicked submit. Thank you.

[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/AtECopAP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the correct validation which suitable for my code. Thank you!

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
                    <label for="retailDefault">Retail Selling Price</label>
            </div><div>
            <input  id="retailDefault" data-role="numerictextbox" 
 name= "retailDefault" data-bind="value: retailDefaultSellingPrice" required 
 validationMessage="Value is required!" />
            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="retailDefault"></span>
            </div>
```